# Too much load running through GFCI?

Tags: electrical

I'm installing a circuit for two 12-amp loads that will plug into separate 15-amp outlets. These will be the only loads on a circuit with a 30 amp breaker. If the first outlet is a 15 amp GFCI and the second outlet is wired in line downstream with the GFCI and the two devices operate simultaneously, will this put too much load on the GFCI?

Comment: Bitcoin miners?

Answer (score 4):

### You can't do that to begin with

You can't put 15A receptacles on a 30A circuit in the first place -- NEC 210.21(B)(3) says no to that plan, and for good reason.

So, rethink your plan (this'd work fine and dandy with a 15A MWBC instead).

Comment: Or a 20 amp circuit can have 2 - 15 amp receptacles on it. But you cannot put 15 or 20 amp receptacles on a 30 amp branch circuit as TPE points out. And if you want 24 amps of load you will need two separate circuits or a Multi-Wire Branch Circuit.

Answer (score 2):

Nope, nope, nope.  You cannot put a 30A breaker on common receptacle circuits, for *so many reasons*.

Your 20A-rated GFCI cannot handle 24A anyway (12A of its own load plus 12A passthru).  Use two GFCIs.  Since  you're using two GFCIs anyway, then as TPE says, **use a MWBC**.

Alternately, get 240V versions of these appliances, and wire this new circuit 240V instead of 120V, with NEMA 6-15 or 6-20 receptacles. Double the voltage means half the current, and that means you have two 6-amp devices, which is no problem for a 15A or 20A circuit.

[image]

*240V NEMA 6-15 dual receptacle. Look familiar?*

Alternately, install a dryer style circuit with 10/3 cable and a NEMA 14-30 receptacle, and have that feed a listed PSU.